# Compilation Error: The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

To start, I have read tons of questions like this but nothing has fixed my issue.  When I publish my project from Visual Studio 2013 to a server, I get the following error:

[image]

Its apparently missing a reference to a library I'm using.  The issue is the dll is getting published (it is in the bin folder on the server).  It seems its having some issue finding the reference?  I've tried copying the dll and putting it in the same directory as the c sharp code.  I've made sure everything is using the same framework.  I have no idea what's happening.  I need some help.  Thanks in advance!

Here is the bin folder:
[image]

Here is the folder on the server:
[image]

As you can see the project is very small right now.
Here is the Default.aspx code:
[image]

Here is the C# code (Default.aspx.cs):
[image]

And here is my web.config:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as images. It is text and should be posted as text.

Comment: Are all of your projects set to compile as the correct framework? Check in Advanced Compiler Settings in the projects properties page, under Compile tab. Ensure that the Target Framework is set correctly. For instance: should be `.NET Framework 4`, not `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.

Comment: In Visual Studio, how do you add the reference? How do you publish?

Comment: @gmiley In the projects page, under the Build tab, Target Framework reads: ".Net Framework 4.5.1". This is the same as my reference.

Comment: @mason To add a reference, I click website, add reference, browse to reference and click OK. To publish, I publish as a File system to my target location. Under settings, file publish options I just have delete all checked.

Comment: is `Copy Local` set in your dll's properties in VS?

Comment: @SutarminAnton I just looked here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx to see how to do it.  They only have information for 2010 and 2008.  I'm using 2013.  Is this still an issue in 2013?

Comment: At least you could make an attempt. Try to rebuild your project with `Copy Local` set to `true` for this dll and see if this dll will be copied into `bin\Release` or whatever folder you are using.

Comment: @SutarminAnton I don't even have that option in my properties section.  I have Auto-refresh Path, File Name, File Path.  Am I in the wrong area?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because I see this property I'm talking about in VS 2015. In `Solution Explorer` go to `References` of your project (it's under your project name, near with `Properties`). Find your dll here. `Right click` -> `Properties`. `Copy Local` should be presented in opened tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake of not formatting the directory on my server using IIS.  If anyone comes across this make sure you do that!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the DbAccess dll is not getting the path

you need to make a folder in your solution and give any name like "ThirdpartyDll".
Paste your dll in this folder and while adding new dll give reference path from this folder and then publish.
On server application will take the same path, which i think you had given from local.

Comment: This didn't do it.  I made a folder called "Dlls" in my solution.  I coped my dll to this folder and added the reference via this folder.  When I published and tried to load the page I got the same error.